# How to create comma seperated string out of Python list?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to mark unused datasets in MySQL from a list in python. How can a list be created in python that will serve the MySQL query?

Here is my approach:

The following python list contains urls

```
item['media_urls'] = [
    {'type': 'image', 'url': 'p1.jpg'}, 
    {'type': 'image', 'url': 'p2.jpg'}
]
```

Create array of available urls. This code does not work as I believe the var needs to be initialised in the beginning and then the comma should not be after the last value:

```
for media_url in item['media_urls']:
    found_media += media_url['url'].', '
```

I also tried:

```
found_media = ','.join(media_url['url'])
# results in: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Update table and set all urls that are not in found_media to "disabled":

```
# pseudo code, I just need the query
$sql = "
    UPDATE tbl
    SET status = 'disabled'
    WHERE URL NOT IN ($found_media)
"
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Join your URLs list into one CSV string (no space after comma !) then use `WHERE !FIND_IN_SET(URL, $found_media)`. Remember - this forbids index usage.

Comment: That sounds about right, I am struggling with creating this CSV string from the python list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use a prepared query with parameters for the URL values to protect against SQL injection. Use a list comprehension to find all the `found_media` values, then use `join` to generate a parameter list for the query and then finally execute the query:

```py
item = {'media_urls': [
    {'type': 'image', 'url': 'p1.jpg'}, 
    {'type': 'image', 'url': 'p2.jpg'}
]}

found_media = [m['url'] for m in item['media_urls']]
params = ','.join(['%s'] * len(found_media))

sql = f'''
UPDATE tbl
SET status = 'disabled'
WHERE URL NOT IN ({params})
'''

cursor.execute(sql, tuple(found_media))
```

Comment: This is the right answer irregardless of what op asked for :-)

Comment: @AllanWind yeah, I've just taken it to its logical conclusion which is to do what is asked in the first sentence rather than the title.

Comment: @AllanWind That looks promissing. I am trying to follow your advise on prepared queries. How would that look like if I need to pass more values to the statement? E.g.:                         UPDATE tbl
                        SET
                            STATUS = 'unused',
                            DATE_EDITED = curdate()
                        WHERE
                            merchant_id = 2
                            AND SKU = '09633907'
                            AND STATUS != 'unused'
                            AND URL NOT IN ({params})

Comment: @merlin if you want to pass the `merchant_id` and `SKU` values as well, just replace the fixed values in the query with `%s`, and use `tuple([2, '09633907'] + found_media)` for the parameters (obviously you can replace those values with variables if required).

Comment: Thank you @AllanWind. That also helped me to understand how to use prepared queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the object needs to be initialized for first case as you observed and there will be extra `,` as well in the end:

```
found_media = ""
for media_url  in item['media_urls']:
    found_media += media_url['url'] + ', '
```

You can use list comprehension with `join()` as:

```
found_media = ','.join([f"'{elt['url']}'" for elt in item['media_urls']])
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to quote the strings to be useful in the query.

Comment: the answer has clearly mentioned: `there will be extra , as well in the end`, I just wanted to point the flaw in the OPs script instead of just providing a different code. Regarding the quoting part, I think you are right but it is not clear from the question and the code presented so I didn't add anything that is not explicitly mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, I realized that after I wrote the initial comment, and subsequently revised comment.

Comment: @AllanWind you are absolutely right, the strings would need to be in quotes to be used in the query as is.

Answer (score 1):

Define item.  Use map to extract each url, quote, then convert that array to a comma separated string with join:

```
item = {
    'media_urls': [
            {'type': 'image', 'url': 'p1.jpg'}, 
            {'type': 'image', 'url': 'p2.jpg'}
    ]
}
found_media = ','.join(map(lambda u: "'%s'" % u['url'], item['media_urls']))
print(found_media)
```

which will print:

```
'p1.jpg','p2.jpg'
```

Comment: This is clean, and correctly applies quotes around the strings which would be required for a query.